# unable to open file via ZCAT command in AIX

Tags: linux, unix, aix

zcat command is used to open or expand the contents of a compressed file without actually uncompressing it.
It can process files with extensions 'gz' , 'z' or 'Z'

I have a file 111300000000.gz in my directory .
Now when i'm doing `zcat 111300000000.gz` ,i'm getting the following error: 
111300000000.gz.Z: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
Why is it adding 'Z' at the end? I also read that zcat doesn't renames the file.
Thanks

Comment: `/usr/bin/zcat` and `/opt/freeware/bin/zcat` are different programs; you need the latter, not the former. Also you could use command `gunzip -c 111300000000.gz`

Comment: i checked both directories /usr/bin/zcat and /opt/freeware/bin/zcat and zcat is in both of them. Also gunzip will uncompress it,i don't want to do that.

Comment: Just try command `/opt/freeware/bin/zcat 111300000000.gz` it will work. Also `gunzip -c 111300000000.gz` will work without creating uncompressed file. Honestly, what's the point in asking questions, if you don't even try what you are suggested?

Comment: i thought you wanted me to check if zcat is installed in /opt/freeware/bin rather than the usual /usr/bin. And thanks it worked.Actually both of them worked.Any alternative for this though? i mean where i do not have to specify the absolute path

Comment: You can reorder your PATH, or simply create a symlink like this: `cd /opt/freeware/bin; ln -s zcat gzcat` (as root-user), then you can use command `gzcat 111300000000.gz`